# Is the word "wareful" archaic?

Tags: word-choice

I have a sentence that runs, "My sense of reassurance was wareful." Is this word archaic? Should I use *wary* instead? Or is the meaning of the sentence just plain ambiguous to begin with?

Comment: How can your sense of anything have another emotion?  Is it animate?  "I was wary" sounds much clearer.

Comment: Did you try looking it up? See the [FAQ](http://english.stackexchange.com/faq).

Comment: I'd call the sentence wrong, rather than ambiguous, even if you use a more common word in place of wareful.

Comment: @Charles Thanks Charles for your comment. That was like a frying pan over the head. The sentence is illogical. However, your suggestion does not quite convey my meaning either. Something like this works best I think: "I was feeling reassured, but not without some reservations/skepticism."

Comment: @DAWR That is very clear!  Much better!

Answer (score 2):

to answer the first question,  [dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/wareful?s=t) says:

> Ware"ful\, a. Wary; watchful; cautious. [Obs.]

Note the *[Obs.]*, which means Obsolete.  So yes, it's not used these days.  (I consider myself pretty well-educated and I've never encountered the word before.)

In reading your sentence, even after checking the dictionary, I'm still not sure what you're trying to convey, so I'd say it's confusing.  Perhaps you mean something like

> I was not feeling reassured at all.

or

> I felt a bit reassured, but overall I was still very wary.

Comment: I don't believe the Dictionary.com entry. Not a single occurrence [in the Google Ngram corpus](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=wareful&year_start=1000&year_end=2012&corpus=0&smoothing=0).

Comment: @MetaEd The OED says it is now only *poetic*, and gives this citation: 1937 G. Frankau *More of Us* xv. 160 ― “Slow went his feet, and wareful As federal agent’s in some gangster joint.”

Comment: @MetaEd, [ngrams/info](http://books.google.com/ngrams/info) says "We only consider ngrams that occur in at least 40 books" in reply to antepenultimate question.  Note, [google Books](https://www.google.com/search?q=wareful&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) shows 7 items, but I imagine 5 or 6 of them are irrelevant.

Comment: @tchrist Sure. But I bet Frankau carried a poetic license.

Comment: @MetaEd Given that he was British, I’d say he was more likely to have carried a poetic licence.